# Run gulp programmatically in memory

Tags: node.js, stream, gulp

**Specific question**

Can I run gulp from node and get a return var from it without manipulating any files, just reading from them?

**More background**

I am trying to build something not unlike [Modernizr's build tool](http://modernizr.com/download/). I have several files on disk and want to give the visitor the chance to select a subset of those in a form and submit it.

What should happen then is the visitor will get a download as an return of the submission (a zip file) with those files he/she selected curated and processed (minifying, concatenation and some other magic).

Now in my craze I created a POC that is a NodeJS app, listening to a port and relies heavily on callbacks to go through each set of the magic to then build all files and zip them up in memory and return it as the result to the request.

That feels dirty though. I think it should all be streams neatly put together for plug and play action BUT I am not sure how. I have never used gulp and I am under the impression it would manipulate files only on disk?

The reason I want to create everything in memory is because I don't want to worry about a garbage collector and multiple sessions overwriting each other.

Comment: but you can create a separate folder where the gulp manipulation happens, once file is ready/download, cleanup that folder... you can have guid folder names, which will avoid overwriting etc

Comment: yes but that logic I was trying to avoid. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gulp works on glob selections. As far as i know there is no existing way (in gulp) to pass specific files other then to hardcode them.

The only way i can concieve of to paramaterize file selection is to either:

a. Create your task so you can pass them in as flags in the CLI for this something like [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) would be useful

b. Set the base dir and create something that will automatically display the files, examining a plugin like [inquirer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer) should help

Comment: So maybe gulp is not the right way? any better ideas?

Comment: think bigger and code your own server side solution could use anything from PHP to Java, that way you can just stick it on a host and access it anywhere.

Comment: yeah I agree. I have to use node though. Will have to learn about streams then...

Comment: requirement from our client... ;)

Comment: Use node as the webserver then?

Comment: I am. Still the node solution I built so far does not look very nice. I am looking for the "proper" way here in node... With gulp I thought I don't have to reinvent the wheel ...

Comment: Gulp's only a local task automater for devs lt was never intended to be used as centralized service even though you could in theory Mcguyver it to do that.

Comment: asked a followup here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150854/how-to-structure-node-application-with-multiple-streams-running-into-one

Answer (score 1):

Can't you write gulp plugin and use it instead of gulp.dest() call? Gulp operate on streams/pipes so may be this will be a solution. I don't think getting result on disk is the only think Gulp can do.

Comment: Yeah you are right and that's what I tried to do. I'll have to revisit this for a refactor later. You are saying when writing a gulp plugin there is a finale pipe that takes it to the disk which I could simply take out and pipe my data to my own process? I very small showcase of that would probably yield the correct answer.

Comment: @Dominik Yes, I believe this is what gulp.dest() does. It takes a pipe and writes out files from it.

Comment: If you edit your answer to show a small example of this I'll change the correct answer to you as that would be the appropriate answer.