# How to structure node application with multiple streams running into one

Tags: node.js, stream

Second question in the series ;)
I am building something very like [Modernizr's build tool](http://modernizr.com/download/). I got a form that includes several modules you can check and a "generate" button. Upon generating the user is supposed to get a zip file with only the files he/she has selected.

I [asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115034/run-gulp-programatically-in-memory) if I could leverage gulp to do this backend magic for me so I didn't had to reinvent the wheel but that turned out to be a one way.

Now I am sitting on my node application and trying to figure out how I can merge multiple streams together in the most efficient way?

I can see it working like this:

```
var Zipping = new Ziping(); //instatiate zip for gathering files

CssStream
    .pipe( new getAllLess() ) //open several files
    .pipe( new concatenateLess() ) //concatenate them
    .pipe( new prepareLess() ) //some dynamic parts have to be replace in the less contents
    .pipe( new compileLess() ) //compile to CSS
    .pipe( Zipping.Add() ) //add to zip

JsStream
    .pipe( new getAllJs() ) //open several files
    .pipe( new concatenateJs() ) //concatenate them
    .pipe( new uglifyJs() ) //uglify them (I can probably combine the above into this step)
    .pipe( Zipping.Add() ) //add to zip

HtmlStream
    .pipe( new getHtml() ) //open several files
    .pipe( new prepareHtml() ) //do some replacements for dynamic parts
    .pipe( Ziping ) //add to zip

//after all three streams finished running

Ziping.compile(); //send zip as response to client
```

This, right off the bat make me wonder how I can "listen" to all three streams in order to finalize the zip? I don't even know if something like this is even possible with node's streams.

The next question is how I can gather several files in a step or whether there is a better more efficient way to do this?

Any help is appreciated.